# vb.net Executing the same sub two times with different arguments

Tags: vb.net, parameter-passing

I have this sub that generates an csv file from the result of a query

```
Private Sub generaReport(classe As String)

    Dim query As String = "select bla bla bla"

    Dim dt As New System.Data.DataTable()
    Using con As New SqlConnection(My.Settings.dbstartConnectionString)
        Using cmd As New SqlCommand(query, con)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ieri", dataDa)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@domani", dataA)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@classe", classe)
            Using sda As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
                sda.Fill(dt)
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using

    Dim elencoCsv As String = ToCSV(dt)

    If classe = "D" Then
        File.Delete(nomeFileCsvD)

        Using writer As New StreamWriter(nomeFileCsvD, True)
            writer.WriteLine(elencoCsv)
        End Using
    Else
        File.Delete(nomeFileCsvV)

        Using writer As New StreamWriter(nomeFileCsvV, True)
            writer.WriteLine(elencoCsv)
        End Using
    End If
    InvioEmail(My.Settings.emails)

    End
End Sub
```

I would call it two times like

```
  Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
            generaReport("D")
            generareport("V")
   End Sub
```

but the second time it runs it still use "D" as parameter. How can I solve this? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As written, you have an [End](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/end-statement?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(vb.End)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework%2CVersion%3Dv4.5.2)%3Bk(DevLang-VB)%26rd%3Dtrue) statement right before the `End Sub` line at the bottom of `generaReport()`.  From the documentation, the `End` statement...

> Terminates execution immediately.

So after executing with the "D" parameter, the entire application closes.  It doesn't run "D" twice, it simply never runs "V".

**Get rid of the `End` statement...**